# enforcing consistency among multiple 1:m relationships

Tags: normalization, database-normalization

Given these business rules:

- Users have 0 or more accounts and all accounts are associated with a single user
- Users have 0 or more assets and all assets are associated with a single user
- An asset may be associated with a single account. If it is assigned to any account, that account must belong to the user associated with the asset.

Assume the following proposed schema:

```
User
-id

Account
-id
-user_id

Asset
-id
-user_id
-account_id (Nullable)
```

It appears there is a weakness in this schema since an asset could be
assigned to an account that belongs to a different user than that
asset. Is this addressed by one of the normal forms leading to a
better schema? If it is not covered via normalization is the best
constraint then on the business logic side?

Comment: "all accounts are associated with a single user" -- Does that mean that no two users can have the same account id number? (Same question for assets.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only part of this (below) that normalization might deal with is the nullable column.  In Chris Date's understanding, if a column allows NULL, then the relation isn't in 1NF.

If you were trying to strictly follow the relational model, I think you'd handle this with an assertion. But most SQL platforms don't support assertions.  In SQL, I believe you're looking for something along these lines. I tested this in PostgreSQL.

```
create table users (
  user_id integer primary key
);

create table accounts (
  user_id integer not null references users (user_id),
  account_id integer not null unique,
  primary key (user_id, account_id)
);

create table assets (
  user_id integer not null references users (user_id),
  asset_id integer not null unique,
  account_id integer null,
  primary key (user_id, asset_id),
  foreign key (user_id, account_id) references accounts (user_id, account_id)
 );

-- Insert 3 users.
insert into users values (1), (2), (3);

-- User 1 has two accounts, user 2 has 3 accounts, user 3 has none.
insert into accounts values 
(1, 100),
(1, 101),
(2, 102),
(2, 103),
(2, 104);

-- User 1 has 1 asset not assocated with an account.
insert into assets values (1, 200, null);

-- User 1 has 1 asset associated with account 101
insert into assets values (1, 201, 101);

-- User 1 tries to associate an asset with account 102, which doesn't belong to user 1.
insert into assets values (1, 202, 102);
[Fails with foreign key violation]

-- User 2 has two assets not associated with an account.
insert into assets values
(2, 500, null),
(2, 501, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest dropping the account_id foreign key completely from table Asset. Since account_id is related to your user table, you can join asset and user, and then perform a left join from user to account (if this is the table where account_id is the primary key). If you get a result from the left join, the asset is linked to an account and the user is the same. This way you force that constraint.

Hope this helps,
Regards

ElChe

Comment: I'm not sure it then still satisfies the 3rd business requirement - that the asset be assigned to one or no accounts. If I get rid of account_id from Asset then there are no explicit assignments of asset to account. The join on asset & user would produce the set of all assets and their corresponding user. I think a further join on Account (via user_id) would not capture the one asset to one or none account, but rather just a cross product (e.g. every asset of a specific user would 'belong' to every account for that user).

Comment: You´re right of course, I forgot about that. How about having a table linking user to account and asset.
account_asset
accountid
assetid

If that isn¨t possible, you´d have to enforce this relationship with businesslogic I guess